# Why am I getting "error: type name is not allowed" with these spaghetti templates?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, crtp

I have the following code with a bit of a "spaghetti" of templates:

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename... Args>
class C {
    /*... */
    Bar& getBar() { /* ... */ }
public:
    template <typename U>
    static void Foo() {
        A a = getA<U>();
        Baz& bar = getBar();
        bar.frob<U>(a); /* @@@ */
    }
    /*... */
}

/* no template */
class D : public C<SomeA, D, const SomeE&> { /* ... */ }

/* no template */
class F : public D { /* ... */}
```

and when I try to compile a function with the following statement:

```
D::Foo<F>();
```

I get the error `type name is not allowed`, on the line marked `@@@`. Why would I be getting that? I know you get it when you try to call a function with a type name, but it doesn't look like I'm doing it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a classic template ambiguity, that unfortunately is hard to notice if you don't know about it. Answer: you need to to write `bar.template frob<U>(a);` Reason: see [**this Q&A**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/819272).

Comment: Huh. Hmm. Can you explain why that would be?

Comment: @einpoklum see update